# RefreshScope bean are not getting updated on zookeeper config node values changed

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, dynamic-properties, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I my trying to implement the **dynamic property** refresh in **spring-boot** application. My config server here is **zookeeper**. But it seems, that there's some issue and without application re-start the values in the config files are not getting updated on runtime, whenever the zookeeper config node changes.

**Bean** (This needs to be refresh without application start whenever the zookeeper node -> prop.host gets updated):

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prop")
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@Slf4j
public class AppProperties {

    @NotEmpty
    private String host;

    @EventListener
    public void onRefreshScopeRefreshed(final RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
        log.info("Got refresh scope event HbaseProperties: {}", event);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>wallet</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.12.15</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>scheduler</module>
        <module>reports</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <spring.retry>1.2.4.RELEASE</spring.retry>
        <lombok>1.18.4</lombok>
        <mysql>8.0.13</mysql>
        <common.lang>3.8.1</common.lang>
        <swagger>2.9.2</swagger>
        <aws>1.12.262</aws>
        <xcelite>1.0.4</xcelite>
        <jdbi>2.78</jdbi>
        <common.utils>4.2.1-RELEASE</common.utils>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${common.lang}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.retry}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-log4j-appender</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
                <version>${jdbi}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
                <version>${aws}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
                <version>${aws}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
                <artifactId>xcelite</artifactId>
                <version>${xcelite}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
                <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.375</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I solved it by adding ```spring.cloud.zookeeper.config.name=your-app-name``` in bootstrap.properties, it seems latest version of ```spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config``` required this to watch the config node ```/config/your-app-name```.